# Show that $\mathbb{E}~|\xi - \mathrm{med}(\xi)| \leq \mathbb{E}~|\xi - \mathbb{E}(\xi)| $

Tags: probability, inequality, median

Assuming $\mu$ is the median of random variable $\xi$, prove, that,

$$\mathbb{E}~|\xi - \mu| \leq \mathbb{E}~|\xi - \mathbb{E}\xi|  $$

The case when  $\mu =  \mathbb{E}\xi $ is trivial, but I have no idea what to do when they are not equal.

Comment: Maybe it will help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180801/the-minimum-of-the-sum

Comment: Actually, $\mathbb{E}~|\xi - \mu| \leq \mathbb{E}~|\xi - x|  $ for every $x$, as differentiating the RHS shows.

Comment: Thanks for posting such a useful link. It helped me very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm going to use $X$ instead of $\xi$, just to make it easier to write and read.) Look at $ g(m):=\mathbb{E}\lvert X-m \rvert$. If the distribution function of $X$ is $F$,  this is
$$ \int_{X \leqslant m} (m-x) \, dF(x) + \int_{X>m} (x-m) \, dF(x). $$

Integrate by parts:
$$ \begin{align} \int_{X \leqslant m} (m-x) \, dF(x) &= \left[ (m-x)F(x) \right]_{-\infty}^m+\int_{X \leqslant m} F(x) \, dx \\
 &= \int_{X \leqslant m} F(x) \, dx \\
\int_{X>m} (x-m) \, dF(x) &= [-(x-m)(1-F(x))]_{m}^{\infty}+\int_{X > m} (1-F(x)) \, dx  \\
&= \int_{X > m} (1-F(x)) \, dx \end{align} $$

Differentiating with respect to $m$ gives
$$ g'(m) = 2F(m)-1. $$
This is

- Zero when $F(m)=1/2$,
- Nondecreasing in $m$.

It follows that $g(m)$ has a minimum exactly when $F(m)=1/2$, which is the definition of the median. Hence $g(\mu) \leqslant g(m)$ for any other $m$, including $\mathbb{E}X$, which is exactly the inequality you want.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Chappers: I think a little bit more care is needed here. It is not given in the question that the CDF of $X$ is continuous so it may happen that $\frac{1}{2}$ is not in the image of CDF $F$.

Comment: @MerylStreep I'm not sure how one would define the median, were that not the case.

Comment: @Chappers: Usually the median is defined as $\inf\{x: F(x) \geq \frac{1}{2}\}$.

Comment: I think fundamentally the point is that $g'(m)$ is nondecreasing, so $g$ is convex. Therefore, it has a unique minimum, since $g'(\pm \infty)=\pm 1$.

Comment: I agree with this.